# Access NSTextBox from another class

Tags: c#

I have my WinForm (Form1) and another class (Class1). Form1 has a textbox with the name of TextBox and I'm wanting to change the text inside TextBox within Class1. How can I do this? I've already checked everywhere and tried all the methods on Stackoverflow and other sources but they all seem to not be working.

EDIT:
I've tried making the TextBox public, but that didn't work.
Then I tried using the following code:

```
private readonly Form1 form;

public Class1(Form1 form) {
    this.fom = form;
}

private void EditText() {
    form.TextBox.Text = .... (TextBox seems to not be an object, even though it is)
}
```

Which also ended up not working. 
Finally once I set the TextBox component modifiers to public inside the visual studio editor it gave me no errors until I ran the program in which it said:

> Error 1   Inconsistent accessibility: field type 'NSTextBox' is less accessible than field 'OverloadBot_Panel.Form1.ConsoleTextBox'   D:\Users\goff-laptop\Desktop\OverloadBotNet\OverloadBot_Panel\OverloadBot_Panel\Form1.Designer.cs   364 26  OverloadBot_Panel

I am using a Theme if that matters at all.

Comment: Could you be a *bit* more specific as to what isn't working? There is a *wealth* of knowledge out there on how to do this.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET Bummer, I loved the answer with public static! It was totally adequate.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET I added a bit more info.

Comment: That code isn't complete (though a start). Could you show the *rest* of that attempt?

Comment: @PeterSchneider I sincerely hope you are being sarcastic.

Comment: What could possibly not work when you made the box public?

Comment: @PeterSchneider making it *static* is going to cause a massive mess, far more than making it public.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET Alright. Updated.

Comment: Ok, it's getting better. Now, did you read the linked duplicates? Try this with a *standard* text box?

Comment: @BradleyDotNET It seems to be working with a standard textbox. And yes I did (:

Comment: @JakeCross Are these "special" text boxes from a library? It looks like one is not marked public, hence the error.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET Yes it is, would I have to go into the library code and edit the "special" textbox. I found the class for the textbox. Any ideas on what I need to change? http://pastebin.com/Va5yVhV3

Comment: @JakeCross I think just doing this in a more reasonably designed manner will fix the problem, rather than hacking again. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you need to do this the *right* way. Or at least a better way than exposing the control directly.

In order to keep tight encapsulation, as well as separation of concerns, you shouldn't be exposing your controls to the outside world *anyways*. Instead, define a method on your form class that sets the text box for you:

```
public void UpdateText(string text)
{
    myTextBox.Text = text;
}
```

And in the caller:

```
private void DoStuff()
{
   form.UpdateText("Test");
}
```

Now the caller doesn't need to know about the internal structure of the form. In fact, if you went through an interface instead, it wouldn't care if it was event *talking* to a form. The class on the other side would simply react to the "UpdateText" message in whatever way it needed to. This design is *much* better in addition to fixing your problem.